# Are traces sent from OpenCensus to OpenTelemetry recognizable

Tags: go, trace, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, opencensus

I have OpenCensus implemented in my Go application and planning on sending [SpanContext](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opencensus.io/trace#SpanContext) to a downstream service that uses OpenTelemetry. The SpanContext would include populated TraceID, SpanID, Tracestate and I'm planning to send the SpanContext in the PubSub message attributes.

I'm wondering if the information within the SpanContext sent downstream will be recognizable by OpenTelemetry?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if the information within the SpanContext sent downstream will be recognizable by OpenTelemetry?

It will be recognizable, and one of the project's goals is to make a reasonable migrations path for `OC` or `OT` users to OTEL since it is a merger of OpenCensus and OpenTracing. And you can look at the OTEL go code to confirm https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/blob/trace/v1.14.0/trace/trace.go#L184-L190